# dropbox API upload NO oAuth possible?

Tags: php, web-applications, oauth, upload, dropbox

So as usual my (maybe not ment to be) use-case is not covered in the oAuth authentication system. as a small group of people (<6), we use dropbox as a centralized sharing filesystem. works perfect for all sorts of stuff. Now, i am building an web application (php/js/css/etc) that uses a SQLite database. I would like the webapp to be able to automagically backup that SQLite database,
and here is the thing... without having to authorize every time. also, authorizing makes no sense because it is not really a random user's dropbox that is used in the app.

Is this at all possible? i know other API's have the possibility to generate an oAuth accesstoken (as to skip the whole auth procedure) for specific use cases (like mine).
Dropbox seems to not have this... am i right?

[edit] i have noticed this library https://github.com/jakajancar/DropboxUploader/ and it **does** also still work, but it is kind of a work-around. i am still looking for a 'nicer', less hacky alternative.

Is there a way to solve this? another service like dropbox (box?) that CAN do this?
Is it at all a bad practice? if so, why?

Comment: Doesn't Dropbox have this? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#access-token

Comment: I do not see that this generates an accesstoken you can persistently use without re-authorizing... it is just step 3 of the oAuth procedure :/

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry about that. Seems like there has to be given the number of third-party services that interact with Dropbox. Hmmm.